# What's the difference between `ng-show` and `ng-hide`?

Tags: angularjs

These attributes are both given either a `true` or `false` value, so what difference is there between them? It would make sense if there weren't values for them.

Am I missing something?

Comment: some developers like to use `ng-show` and some - `ng-hide`.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129912/ng-show-true-but-still-has-class-ng-hide

Comment: This is why having both `if` and `unless` is not a good idea. It's pointless to have two syntaxes for essentially the same time.

Comment: Yeah. Okay. I don't see the point in this. It seems so redundant.

Answer (score 3):

With `ng-show` the element is shown if the expression is **true**, it will hide if it is **false**

On the other hand with `ng-hide` the element is hidden if the expression is **true** and it will be shown if it is **false**.

Just two sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 3):

On a project I was working on before, I found having the option of both `ng-show` and `ng-hide` useful. The reason being is because I had a link in my navbar that was only supposed to show if the user was on a specific view. Here is that scenario:

```
<li ng-hide="isActive('/about') || isActive('/contact')" ng-class="{ 'vert-nav-active': isActive('/investigator')}" class="top-buffer">
<a href="#/investigator" class="buff-sides navListLinks">Investigator Portal</a>
</li>
```

Now, you might say, well you could just make the `isActive('/about') || isActive('/contact')` return the opposite Boolean and change the `ng-hide` to `ng-show` and every thing will stay the same but as you can see I'm also using this function to determine which link I'm on. If I reverse this logic, it will look like I'm on every link except the actual link I'm on. Granted I *could* write another function for the `ng-show` but I like reusing code that's already there.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth mentioning is `ng-if` which takes a boolean expression just like `ng-show` and `ng-hide` but rather than just showing/hiding the elements depending on the expression, it completely removed the element from the DOM if the expression is `false` and put the element back in the DOM if the expression becomes `true`

Answer (score 1):

i have a good scenario, let say you want to show one attribute or another depending on a validation, but not both, so using both ng-show and ng-hide like this:

```
<div ng-show="validation"></div>
<div ng-hide="validation"></div>
```

if the validation is true it would show the first div, but if it is false it would show the second div...
this can be done in many more ways but is a cleaver solution for a tricky problem :D

Answer (score 0):

ng-show will only display the element IF the expression is true...

```
<span ng-show="true">Will Show </span>
<span ng-show="false">Will not Show </span>
```

ng-hide will not display the element IF the expression is true, but will display if the expression is false.

```
<span ng-hide="true">Will not display</span>
<span ng-hide="false">Will display</span>
```